# Combine Dynamic datasource routing with spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm using Dynamic datasource routing as indicated in this blog post:
http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

This works fine, but when I combine it with `spring-data-rest` and browsing of my generated repositories I (rightfully) get an exception that my lookup-key is not defined (I do not set a  default).

How and where can I hook into the Spring data rest request handling to set the lookup-key based on 'x' (user authorizations, path prefix, or other), before any connection is made to the database?

Code-wise my datasource configuration just mostly matches the blogpost at the top, with some basic entity classes, generated repositories and Spring Boot to wrap everything together. If need I could post some code, but there's nothing much to see there.

Comment: i might be missing your question...isn't the CustomerRoutingDataSource in the example doing the type of work you want?

Comment: Not when you want to combine it with the generated rest api from spring data rest

Comment: Why didn't you set a default? Do you use Spring Security too? Then I can provide a simple solution.

Comment: @ksokol I'm not setting a default as different databases concern data from different clients, don't want to mix those up. I'm indeed using Spring security, so I'd like to know what your take on this would be.

Comment: @Tim added my idea as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first idea is to leverage Spring Security's [`authentication`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) object to set current datasource based on `authorities` attached to the authentication.
Of course, you can put the lookup key in a custom [`UserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) object or even a custom Authentication object, too. For sake of brevity I`ll concentrate on a solution based on authorities.
This solution requires a valid authentication object (anonymous user can have a valid authentication, too). Depending on your Spring Security configuration changing authority/datasource can be accomplished on a per request or session basis.

My second idea is to work with a `javax.servlet.Filter` to set lookup key in a thread local variable before Spring Data Rest kicks in. This solution is framework independent and can be used on a per request or session basis.

**Datasource routing with Spring Security**

Use [`SecurityContextHolder`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) to access current authentication's authorities. Based on the authorities decide which datasource to use.
Just as your code I'm not setting a defaultTargetDataSource on my `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.

```
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        Set<String> authorities = getAuthoritiesOfCurrentUser();
        if(authorities.contains("ROLE_TENANT1")) {
            return "TENANT1";
        }
        return "TENANT2";
    }

    private Set<String> getAuthoritiesOfCurrentUser() {
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        return AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authorities);
    }
}
```

In your code you must replace the in memory [`UserDetailsService`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) (inMemoryAuthentication) with a UserDetailsService that serves your need.
It shows you that there are two different users with different roles `TENANT1` and `TENANT2` used for the datasource routing.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user1").password("user1").roles("USER", "TENANT1")
            .and()
            .withUser("user2").password("user2").roles("USER", "TENANT2");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example: https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/sdr-routing-datasource-spring-security/spring-data

**Datasource routing with javax.servlet.Filter**

Create a new filter class and add it to your `web.xml` or register it with the [`AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html), respectively.

```
public class TenantFilter implements Filter {

    private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(";\\s*tenant\\s*=\\s*(\\w+)");

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String tenant = matchTenantSystemIDToken(httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        Tenant.setCurrentTenant(tenant);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            Tenant.clearCurrentTenant();
        }
    }

    private String matchTenantSystemIDToken(final String uri) {
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(uri);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Tenant class is a simple wrapper around a static [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

```
public class Tenant {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> TENANT = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) { TENANT.set(tenant); }

    public static String getCurrentTenant() { return TENANT.get(); }

    public static void clearCurrentTenant() { TENANT.remove(); }
}
```

Just as your code I`m not setting a defaultTargetDataSource on my AbstractRoutingDataSource.

```
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        if(Tenant.getCurrentTenant() == null) {
            return "TENANT1";
        }
        return Tenant.getCurrentTenant().toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Now you can switch datasource with `http://localhost:8080/sandbox/myEntities;tenant=tenant1`. Beware that tenant has to be set on every request. Alternatively, you can store the tenant in the `HttpSession` for subsequent requests.

Here is a complete example: https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/sdr-routing-datasource-url/spring-data

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-detail reply. Your approach indeed looks like something that could work, but sadly I have not been able to implement it due to issues in another part of my codebase this week. I hope to get round to it shortly and will mark your solution as the answer once I can confirm it works. Thanks again!

Comment: So sorry I only got around to it now, but it works like a charm, thank you very much! I went with the Filter based approach, as tenants and databases are in a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @ksokol I went with the Filter based approach, it works perfectly man! I just wanted to add, instead of using pattern in filter, you could send the tenant as a parameter (for example "?tenant=tenant1"), and then do something like  Tenant.setCurrentTenant(httpRequest.getParameter("tenant")... It;s more clear as I solution.

Comment: @meriton-husaj I know that you can use query parameter too. I prefer a semicolon in order to distinguish between page and application wide parameters (think of 'JSESSIONID')

Comment: @ksokol I have the same problem, its just my tenantContextId is in url and not a query param, any ideas there?