# Spring multiple database configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to switch between 2 different databases based on the request from web. Am developing this using spring mvc.

Along with that I am using JDBC for own database configuration. This I have configured with spring bean. By default this connection should be always connected

```
<bean id='' class=''/>
```

As per the requirement I have to switch between multiple databases based on the selection in the web. Let's say I have SERVER 1 and SERVER 2. SERVER 1 for India and SERVER 2 for US
Now I have to configure the DB details for SERVER 1 and SERVER 2 based on the request. My question is how can I store these 2 server details in my applicationn? That means Can I use enum class to load / some properties file/ beans ?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a `RoutingDatasource`. Please take a look at my answer to a similar question. It contains even a working example you can check out. Link to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25083710/combine-dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring-data-rest/25418873#25418873

Comment: @ksokol You mean apart from the existing connection, I can connect to another database ??

Comment: You'll need the connection configuration in advance. You can not connect to a new database during runtime easily. Honestly, I have never seen such a requirement in my lifetime. If you know your databases in advance `RoutingDatasource` does the job for you.